# Why cant a polar dielectrics molecules ever completely align with an applied electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, polarization, dielectric

In my electro statics course my professor said that the molecules in a polar dielectric cant ever fully align with an external electric field as they will want to then 'turn back on one another', so you can only get partial alignment.

Can someone clarify on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your professor is correct. Although the molecules align with the field there are also electrostatic forces between the polarized molecules themselves. To illustrate this, check the following link:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dielec.html

Note how some of the positive regions of the dipoles repulse one another as well as some of the negative regions. The dipoles tend to arrange themselves so as to minimize these forces, thus you will not find perfect polarization.

Hope this helps.